# FOSS Image viewer for Linux with easy rename capability

Tags: linux, open-source, images, image-viewer, rename

I'm looking for an image viewer for Linux/Unix desktop environments - no need for it to be fancy or anything - but with a particular feature: As I view an image, I should be able to rename it.

Somehow, the ones I have installed don't offer this feature: LXImage, comix. I know there are a lot of image viewers out there - but which of them has this feature?

Requirements:

- Gratis
- Libre
- Supports X on Linux

Desired:

- Actively maintained
- Not resource-heavy

Comment: Just FYI: The reason some applications have difficulty renaming a file while it is open is because they are creating a lock when the file is open.  The lock has to be removed, the file renamed, and then the file reopened.  It's not hard, but many applications don't have this functionality.  FWIW, it's not a Linux thing... Windows applications often have the same issue.

Comment: @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket: But why would they need to lock the file, at all? Wouldn't they just read it into memory?

Comment: Great question. There are multiple ways to do it, but often developers choose to keep a lock on open files to prevent other applications from modifying (or deleting) them.  In most cases, it is not necessary, and I prefer software that does not unnecessarily lock open files.

Answer (score 1):

[gThumb](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gthumb) is another one that can rename files from the context menu.

Answer (score 0):

[gwenview](https://apps.kde.org/en/gwenview) supports this. If you press F2 while viewing an image, you get to rename it:

[image]

- It's a KDE app, so it's FOSS.
- It's actively maintained - latest release is from this month.

Answer (score 0):

[Nomacs](https://nomacs.org/features/) is a simple, lightweight and a very powerful tool.

It has renaming capabilities, I have not use that though.

Comment: Can it rename an image while I'm viewing it?